# do-while with OR operator doesn't work for some reason

Tags: c++

I suppose this one is really simple, but I can't figure out what's the problem. The question is:

If this works:

```
char input;
do {
    cin >> input;
} while (input != '1');
system ("pause");
```

Then, why this doesn't:

```
char input;
do {
    cin >> input;
} while ((input != '1') || (input != '2'));
system ("pause");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If input is not 1 or input is not 2. Think about that logic again.

Comment: Huh, doesn't the compiler normally print a warning if it finds a non-trivial tautology in an if-statement or a loop condition? (At least with -W.)

Comment: @Kay, Now that you mention it, I'll bet it does. GCC would look something like `warning: condition will always be true`.

Comment: Neither g++ 4.7.1 nor Visual C++ 2012 issues a warning for this case at `-Wall`.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, Yeah, I just tried it myself. I'm trying to think of when it does because I know I've seen that error.

Comment: I would expect a warning for, e.g. `do { } while (true);`, at least at high warning levels.  Visual C++ 2012 emits warning C4127 at warning level 4; I can't figure out how to get GCC to emit any warning, even with trivial constant conditions.  Perhaps it requires additional warning options other than `-Wall` and `-Wextra`.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, Check out this one I found. I think this might have been what I was thinking of. http://liveworkspace.org/code/e43399ba6082532525bf4e5392f39d09

Comment: It would be better as `while (cin >> input && input != '1' && input != 2) ;` - as is, someone types 'x' and your program enters an infinite loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(input != '1') || (input != '2')
```

This expression always evaluates to `true` because `input` cannot be both `'1'` and `'2'` at the same time.

It is more likely that you want to use `&&`:  replacing `||` with `&&`, the expression would evalute to `true` if `input` is neither `'1'` nor `'2'`.

Comment: I can see clearly now! Seems it's time for me to go to bed. Thanks.

Comment: @chris Sure it is. It's just this expression is all messed up. It insults my intelligence. I feel a bit ashamed now for having problems with such simple expressions. :D

Comment: @eqagunn This mistake is actually *really* common.